# How to generate methods dynamically in Java

Tags: java, generics, methods

I was wondering, what if I have the following case:

```
public class MyObject<T> {
   private T myTObject;

   public void setMyTObject(T m) { 
       myTObject = m;
   } 

   public T getMyTObject() { 
       return myTObject;
   }
}
```

And now I want that class to react something like these:

```
MyObject<ObjectA> objA = new MyObject<ObjectA>();
ObjectA objAInstance = objA.getObjectA();
```

or

```
objA.setObjectA(otherObjectAInstance);
```

Is there a way to dynamically create methods based on T class name?
Or should I better extend ObjectA to MyObject and create those methods using super.get/seMyObject()?

**For clarification:**

The idea is to have a getter and setter method generated dynamically
so, if I create an instance of:

```
MyObject<A> objA = new MyObject<A>();
```

I would be able to call method:

```
objA.getA();
```

getA() will call internally getMyTObject() or just return myTObject

so MyObject may react based on T class and generate the corresponding method.

I have updated member attribute to differentiate from MyObject class, it may lead to confusion. also fixed Method return and parameter Type.

Comment: Well, it's possible to [generate classes and methods on the fly with byte code generators](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/manual.html), but it's not easy.  There's also a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class which uses reflection.  But overall you're better off using using extension if you can.

Comment: I think it's case to watch for java reflection..

Comment: I don't read anything about why you want to do that? Just because you can or is the only reason that you find it a better naming convention for your getters and setter to depend on the actual generic type? In the latter case, simply forget about it, no one does that, it's not worth it, just use generic names for your getters and setters and everythign is fine. There's really no benefit, all modern IDE will tell you about the concrete objects types returned and set. Look at the standard Java API and generic classes like List<T>, Map<K, V> and such.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Answer is completely changed.

Sounds like you want to use something through reflection. The problem with truly dynamically generating the method names is that, as others have commented, it would have to be done in bytecode which means that other classes trying to use your dynamic classes don't have Java code to refer to. It *can* be done, but it would be a mess.

Instead, here's a possible solution using generics. Please note that this is something of a quick and dirty hack; I leave it to you to refine it. You define an interface with the getters and setters you want, with whatever you want them named:

```
package com.example.dcsohl;

public interface IntegerWrapper {

    public Integer getInteger();
    public void setInteger(Integer i);

}
```

And then, to use them, you use this class to do the heavy lifting. Note that the error checking isn't very good; for example, it doesn't check that "getFoo" at all corresponds to the name of the class being passed in; nor does it validate that the "foo" in "getFoo" matches the "setFoo" method. This is something you can improve on.

```
package com.example.dcsohl;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class ProxyWrapper<T> implements InvocationHandler {

    Class<T> clazz = null;
    T myvalue = null;

    public static <W,T> W getInstance(Class<W> clazz, Class<T> clazz2) {
        ProxyWrapper<T> wrapper = new ProxyWrapper<T>();
        wrapper.setClass(clazz2);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        W proxy = (W)Proxy.newProxyInstance(clazz.getClassLoader(), new Class[] {clazz}, wrapper);
        return proxy;
    }

    private void setClass(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
            throws Throwable {
        // getter has no arguments
        if (method.getName().startsWith("get") && (args == null || args.length == 0)) {
            return myvalue;
        } else if (method.getName().startsWith("set") && args.length == 1) {
            Object o = args[0];
            if (o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                T val = (T)o;
                myvalue = val;
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        return null;
   }


}
```

Finally, to use it, here's a quick sample:

```
package com.example.dcsohl;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer foo = 5;

        IntegerWrapper wrapper = ProxyWrapper.getInstance(IntegerWrapper.class, Integer.class);
        wrapper.setInteger(foo);

        Integer bar = wrapper.getInteger();
        System.out.println(bar);
    }

}
```

It seems like a lot of work just to avoid writing simple wrapper classes, and you'd be right, but reflection has its uses, and this is something of a sampler.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question as far as I understand it. What he wants to do is have the name of the method itself be `getObjectA()` instead of `getT()` or `getMyObject()`.

Comment: Ohhh. You're right, I overlooked that. Too focussed on the method signature and not so much the name.

Comment: Sorry about that, I miswrote the method names, I have fixed the question accordingly, NoseKnowsAll got the idea. At the end I want to avoid creating a bunch of classes that extend to MyObject<T> which only implements getTObject()/setTObject(T arg)

Comment: Ok, I completely changed my answer to go with a reflection-based approach. Partly because I don't know how to do fancy bytecode stuff, and partly because this will be more practicable for reasons I explain up top.

Comment: Thanks guys for the light! will analyze your recommendations.